# C++ private pointer "leaking"?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pointers

I'm going to create a class to hold a long list of parameters that will be passed to a function.  Let's use this shorter example:

```
class ParamList{

public:
    ParamList(string& a_string);
    string& getString(); //returns my_string
private:
    string& my_string;
}
```

My question is this: my_string is private, yet I'm returning the reference to it.  Isn't that called something like private pointer leaking in C++?  Is this not good programming practice?  I want callers of getString to be able to get the reference and also modify it.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
jbu

edit1: callers will use getString() and modify the string that was returned.

Comment: Having references as members is dubious practice, unless you know exactly what you are doing. But I don't see any pointers in this code.

Comment: OK. I do not know what I'm doing. What if my_string were a pointer, and getString returned a pointer to a string?

Comment: It should still return a `const string*`

Comment: It's more of a question of "why does this class exist?"  It doesn't "own" the string object at all, so why pass around this class rather than the ACTUAL string object?  It's just another layer of a wrapper.  It doesn't even allocate a string, just a reference to a string, so somewhere else still has to own the string, either higher up the stack (possibly in another class), or in a global variable.  Either way, WHY does this class exist?

Comment: @kevin: it exists each parameter object has members that GO TOGETHER.  a LIST of parameter objects is passed to the function.

Answer (score 3):

Returing a private reference is perfectly okay so long as:

A. That is a `const` reference, and you have documented when that reference can be invalidated or
B. That reference is intended to be modified (i.e. `std::vector<T>::operator[]`)

While there are useful cases for returning a non-const reference you should usually avoid it. This is covered in [Scott Meyers' Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) (3rd Edition, Item 28): Avoid returning "handles" to object internals, if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to decide if the ParamList is going to own the string or just "know about it". The way you've written it, with `string& my_string`, means that it just has a handle onto someone else's string. In that case, it's not (much of) a problem for some to modify the string since ParamList doesn't own it in the first place!

If you want ParamList to have a full master copy of the parameters (depends on the problem you're trying to solve), do something like this:

```
class ParamList{

public:
    ParamList(const string& a_string); // do a strcpy in here.

    const string& getString(); //returns my_string
    void setString(const string& new_string); //do a strcpy here too.
private:
    string my_string;
}
```

Note that it's probably better to use set and get functions anyway rather than returning a non-const reference, just so ParamList can have a little more control over how its members are modified.

Comment: @Neil: shorthand for "copy from one string to the other".

Comment: Name of function in standard library - possibility for confusion: high.

Comment: @Neil: Not to mention it's as simple as `my_string = new_string`.